# Windows 10 + Cygwi64 + Ansible + Nitro Netscaler SDK Problem (could not find nitro python sdk)

Tags: python, ansible, cygwin

I installed Cygwin64 including Ansible2.8 on Windows10 (System1).
I then tried to execute a playbook which uses module "netscaler_server" which fails with

```
failed: [localhost -> 164.28.47.183] (item=10.3.128.39) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "item": "10.3.128.39", "msg": "Could not load nitro python sdk"}
```

I copied the folder "nssrc" from the Nitro Python SDK(v.11.1) to "C:\cygwin64\lib\python3.7\site-packages\" but **error still occurs**.

Then I installed this configuration on another Windows10 (System2) and **everything worked fine** but I can't find any obvious differences in the Cygwin installation.

This is same on both systems:

```
$ ansible --version
ansible 2.8.4
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/home/A785298/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.7.4 (default, Jul 21 2019, 14:43:25) [GCC 7.4.0]
```

I would like to ask you helping me find the difference between System1 and System2. Any ideas?

Comment: you are mixing a windows development enviroment  `Nitro Python SDK`, with a vanilla-Unix enviroment as  `Cygwin` and its python. You shoud use Mingw64 (http://mingw-w64.org/) and a windows version of Python for Windows compilation not Cygwin.

Comment: Ok, but it's working fine with Windows 10 on System 2. Even with mixing stuff.